# Cocoa/Obj-c: How to fetch string from english localizable.strings irrespective of preferred localization

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

In my application I want to show some messages at some place in english language. For that it is required that the messages should always be read from English.lproj/Localizable.strings file irrespective of the localization selected by user. I can not use NSLocalizedString method for this purpose now because it always returns the localized string. Please suggest a way to read strings from default (or development) localization resource file.

Answer (score 5):

You're going to have to do it manually, like this:

```
- (NSString *)englishLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString *)key inTable:(NSString *)table {
  if (table == nil) {
    table = @"Localizable";
  }

  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:table 
                                                   ofType:@"strings" 
                                              inDirectory:nil 
                                          forLocalization:@"en"];
  if (path == nil) {
    return nil;
  }

  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
  id plist = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:data 
                                                       options:0 
                                                        format:NULL 
                                                         error:NULL];

  if (![plist isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
    return nil;
  }

  return [plist objectForKey:key];
}
```

So, here's what's going on.

- Get the name of the table (strings file) from the parameters, defaulting to `@"Localizable"` if you happened to pass in `nil`
- Find the path of `{table}.strings` inside the `en.lproj` folder
- return `nil` if the file doesn't exist
- read the file in as a blob of data
- attempt to decode the blob as a property list.  This works because `.strings` files are in the old-style plist format, so we can use this plist parser to build it into an `NSDictionary` for us
- if we didn't get an `NSDictionary` back, return `nil`
- return whatever the dictionary has for the request key (may return `nil` if the key can't be found)

The reading and deserializing bit can potentially be expensive, so I'd recommend caching the appropriate information in a property somewhere.

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Only change i made here is i read the file in dictionary itself

NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path];

Comment: Oh, nice - I wasn't aware of pathForResource:ofType:inDirectory:forLocalization:

Answer (score 1):

I recommend putting these special strings in their own strings table, and then only putting that table in the English localization. This way you can use `NSLocalizedStringFromTable()` as Benedict suggests. The localization functions will search through locales using the user's preferred search order until they find the requested file.

An advantage of this approach is that you may be able to avoid translating strings that only appear in this table.

Comment: But these special messages are also need to be localized. So I can not put them in another file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`NSLocalizedStringFromTable`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/Reference/reference.html)? It lets you specify which file to use for the strings.

Comment: -1 won't work. this lets you specify the name of the `.strings` file, not the language.